# Rails Admin field filter in a has_one through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin, rails-models

I have a `Remediation` model which inherits from `AssessmentHighRiskFactor` model and added some custom show fields from other tables using relationships. The fields are visible and working fine, but I can't use the filter by 'cycle' in the admin panel (throws errors).

- It is trying to access the cycle column which belongs to (`institution_company_topics` table) in the `assessment_high_risk_factor` table.
- PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table `assessments` or `institution_company_topics`
- Unknown column (because it is not doing the filter in the corresponding table)

###### Remediation model:

```
class Remediation < AssessmentHighRiskFactor
  has_one :company, through: :assessment
  has_one :institution_company_topic, through: :assessment

  def cycle
    institution_company_topic&.cycle
  end

  rails_admin do
    def helper_text
      'Manage Remediation'
    end

    list do
      field :cycle do
        queryable true
        searchable true
        filterable true
      end
    end
end
```

- Already tried with scopes (with custom query to join tables)
- Using bindings objects
- Using `searchable [{InstitutionCompanyTopic => :cycle}]` or `[:cycle]`

###### AssessmentHighRiskFactor model:

```
  class AssessmentHighRiskFactor < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :assessment
  end
```

###### Assessment model:

```
  class Assessment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :institution_company_topic, optional: true
    has_many :assessment_high_risk_factors, dependent: :destroy
  end
```

###### InstitutionCompanyTopic model:

```
  class InstitutionCompanyTopic < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :assessments, dependent: :destroy
  end
```

`gem 'rails_admin', '~> 2.1.0'`

Any ideas would be good.

Comment: Take a look at custom scopes, I think you can define a custom scope that's the default one where you can do the right SQL.

Comment: Where do you think I can define the custom scope?